# sharepoint workflow email hyperlink changing https to http

Tags: 2013, workflow, sharepoint-email

I made a workflow that sends an email with a sharepoint hyperlink. This hyperlink must be accessible from an outside network so it has to be an https link. I have hardcoded a "click here" hyperlink which begins with https however when the actual workflow is executed the resulting "click here" contains a http hyperlink. This then does not load for the users unless they manually add an "s" to the link. What is causing this issue? why would it forcibly change the hyperlink that I typed out? and how can I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a caching problem as none of the changes to workflows were showing after saving and publishing. 
For others who run into this problem the solution can be found here 
[Workflow is updated but there is no change?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/228101/workflow-is-updated-but-there-is-no-change)